# How to detect if Application shortcut is created

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect if the shorcut is created on homescreen.

I have being trying to do this, found it somewhere

```
<receiver android:name="DeleteShortCut">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>               
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

But, com.android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT, nowhere in developers doc.

Also tried using permission,
    < uses-permission      android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>

Broadcast reveiver is not detecting anything.

Anyone, any idea, how to detect if shortcut is created.
Thanks